# SQL query question, how to make a query that outputs all entries of two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables, `CITIES` and `FLIGHTS`:

CITIES

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York |
| 2 | Paris |
| 3 | Tokyo |
| 4 | Amsterdam |

FLIGHTS

| id | departure_id | arrival_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |

I need to write a query that finds all the flight connections.

The desired output would be:

| departure_city | arrival_city |
| --- | --- |
| New York | Paris |
| New York | Tokyo |
| Paris | Tokyo |
| Paris | Amsterdam |

How to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join for that. Both inner join and left join will serve your purpose:

Query with left join:

```
Select c.name as departure_city, ct.name as arrival_city from FLIGHTS f 
left join CITIES c on f.departure_id=c.id
left join CITIES ct on f.arrival_id = ct.id
```

Outupt:

| departure_city | arrival_city |
| --- | --- |
| New York | Paris |
| New York | Tokyo |
| Paris | Tokyo |
| Paris | Amsterdam |

Query with inner join:

```
Select c.name as departure_city, ct.name as arrival_city from FLIGHTS f 
inner join CITIES c on f.departure_id=c.id
inner join CITIES ct on f.arrival_id = ct.id
```

Output:

| departure_city | arrival_city |
| --- | --- |
| New York | Paris |
| New York | Tokyo |
| Paris | Tokyo |
| Paris | Amsterdam |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5a500e8765e6afbef34e190b44d11a10)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do two joins:

```
SELECT departure.name AS departure, 
arrival.name AS arrival
FROM cities AS departure 
JOIN flights f ON departure.id = f.departure_id
JOIN cities arrival ON arrival.id = f.arrival_id;
```

Without further information, it's unclear if you want to do a left or inner join, if you need a where clause, if you need an order by etc. Maybe it would be better to learn some SQL basics and then ask a more precise question if necessary.
Try out if you want: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39a8df85741b0a37b8dffa9e8d7e41e8)

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use below SQL:

```
SELECT c1.NAME, c2.NAME FROM CITIES c1, CITIES c2, flights f WHERE c1.id = f.departure_id AND c2.id = f.arrival_id;
```

The prepared statement is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE CITIES(id int, name varchar(32));

INSERT INTO CITIES values(1, 'New York'), (2, 'Paris'), (3, 'Tokyo'), (4, 'Amsterdam');

CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS(id int, departure_id int, arrival_id int);

INSERT INTO FLIGHTS VALUES(1,1,2), (2,1,3), (3,2,3), (4,2,4);
```

Comment: It's very obsolete and bad style to avoid using JOIN when joining tables.

Comment: Please link some proofs where we should use JOIN when joining tables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause